Pyside (pyqt) how to control UI through qthread? what is the correct way for my example
I'm creating a program in pyside, where most of the functions will be linked through threads, as they are time-consuming functions. and the interface should work.
but I need to have control of some UI elements within the threaded function.
This is an example of my code, where a thread starts. it modifies the UI labels. but I have the error "QObject::setParent: Cannot set parent, new parent is in a different thread"
What is the correct way to make this code work?


from PySide2.QtCore import *
from PySide2.QtGui import *
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *
import sys, time

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):


    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()


        # set central widget
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        lay = QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)

        self.button = QPushButton("Conectar")
        self.status = QLabel("Status")
        self.status.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.conta = QLabel("Valor conta")
        self.conta.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.tipo = QLabel("Tipo conexão")
        self.tipo.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

        lay.addWidget(self.button)
        lay.addWidget(self.status)
        lay.addWidget(self.conta)
        lay.addWidget(self.tipo)

        self.status.hide()
        self.conta.hide()
        self.tipo.hide()


class thread(QThread): 

    def __init__(self,target=None, args=()):
        super().__init__()
        self._target = target
        self._args = args

    def run(self):
        if self._target:
            self._target(*self._args)


def conectar():
    self.status.show()

    self.status.setText('Buscando credenciais no servidor')
    time.sleep(1)
    ### chama funções do servidor
    self.status.setText('Usuário validadado, iniciando conexão')
    time.sleep(1)
    ### chama funções que fazem conexão da api
    self.status.setText('Conectado com sucesso')
    time.sleep(1)

    self.status.hide()

    self.conta.show()
    self.tipo.show()
    self.conta.setText('R$ 150.00')
    self.tipo.setText('Demo')


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
self = MainWindow()

self.qthread =  thread(target=conectar)
self.button.clicked.connect(lambda: self.qthread.start())

self.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())

I hope to be able to modify the UI elements from within the thread.
but in some functions there are several elements, I don't know how to do this with signal and slot.

It's a general rule of UI frameworks, Qt or anybody else, that UI can only interact with a single thread.

You cannot do it like this because UI elements are not thread safe and shall never be accessed from external threads. The fact that you're using a function to do those "time consuming functions" doesn't clarify how those are eventually called: if you just call them sequentially, or they have their own threads, therefore you should provide a [mre] that is less abstract than this one.

This example I gave is very similar to the one I use.
When clicking the button, the connection function starts.
This function needs to update the text of some labels, and also hide other labels from the interface.
What is the correct way to send a signal to the main thread to hide these labels?

The only proper way to update the UI from another thread is by using signals, which 99% of the time is done by using a subclass (QThread or QObject moved to a QThread) having its own signals. Your conectar() function would then be run in that thread and will emit those signals (instead of trying to directly call functions such as setText()) when you need them; those signals will be then connected to the functions that eventually update the UI in the main thread. In your case, you'll probably have different signals, one for updating the status, another for hiding/showing widgets, etc.

Note that it's possible to do that by avoiding further subclasses. But since using signals is mandatory for cross-thread communication (especially with the UI) and you specifically need different modes of communicate with the UI (therefore, custom signals), at least one subclass implementing those signals must exist, because signals can only be declared at the class level. You already have one, so the signals must be added to it. You may eventually emit them from conectar, using a global reference to the thread instance, but I would strongly discourage it.

Further notes: 1. self is a conventional keyword in Python, always used in the context of a class (its instance methods); creating a reference named self as a global object is a terrible choice, especially if used out of the context in which it's normally expected (instance methods); 2. almost any language has a convention suggesting to use different naming standards to identify specific types (possibly unique, such as classes or constants) in order to easily tell them apart from others (variables, functions, etc); the most common ones (including »

» Python) always suggest to use names starting with Uppercase letters for the former, and lowercase for the latter; calling a class thread (with a lower "t") is a terrible choice as much as the usage of self noted above; please take your time to read the Style Guide for Python Code; 3. use lambda only when necessary: connect(lambda: self.qthread.start()) is pointless, use connect(self.qthread.start). Finally, try to improve your research skills, as the error you posted gives hundreds of results (even by restricting them to StackOverflow alone).

Thanks friend, I'll take a look at how I can improve this code.
about signals and slots.. can you give me an example of how to create them? I perhaps needed a class where I could leave the signal variable, after all my interface has several labels that need to be changed through other threads. is there any way to do this?
